# React native textinput multiline is not being pushed up by keyboard

Tags: react-native, keyboard, textinput

I have a TextInput with multiLine true. However, after two lines the text disappear behind the keyboard. I have tried wrapping the TextInput in KeyboardAvoidingView, but it doesn't work.

The keyboard does push up the TextInput when I unfocus the TextInput and then click on the bottom line. Any idea how I can make the last line of the TextInput stay on top of the keyboard?

The code:

```
<View style={styles.descriptionFlexStyle}>
    <Text
       style={[
         styles.headerTextStyle,
         { marginTop: Window.height * 0.04 }
        ]}> Please fill in a reason </Text>
        <ScrollView>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.reasonTextInput}
            placeholder="Reason"
            value={reasonText}
            multiline={true}
            onChangeText={input =>
               this.setState({
                   reasonText: input
               })
            }
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            ref="reasonTextInput"
            />
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: Are you testing on ios or android ? Is your TextInput height limited ? I personnaly set textinput height depending on maximum number of characters the user can enter in multiline TextInput.

Comment: I'm testing for both. Height is not set, it just increases on new line. I can always set it to a max height yes, but it's not what I'm looking for. I want the keyboardavoidingview to work

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok i have finally solved it using "KeyboardAvoidingView". I did two things. First i removed the height on my TextInput and then i set the behavior attribute on the "KeyboardAvoidingView" to "padding". Works perfect for me now. Let me know if this help! :)

Comment: I have the same issue and `KeyboardAvoidingView` isn't working, even with no `height` and behavior attribute to `padding`. The issue is still open in github so I guess that it's not solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

hello my dear you must use `KeyboardAvoidingView` Component from React-Native and put a behavior on it like below :

```
  <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={'postion' || 'height' || 'padding'}>
    <View style={styles.descriptionFlexStyle}>
        <Text
           style={[
             styles.headerTextStyle,
             { marginTop: Window.height * 0.04 }
            ]}> Please fill in a reason </Text>
            <ScrollView>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.reasonTextInput}
                placeholder="Reason"
                value={reasonText}
                multiline={true}
                onChangeText={input =>
                   this.setState({
                       reasonText: input
                   })
                }
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                ref="reasonTextInput"
                />
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: As I said in my question, I have already tried KeyboardAvoidingView with behaviour and it doesn't work. If I start writing in the text input, the first 2 lines will stay over the keyboard, but the third line an so on will be behind the keyboard.. The problem is really that the KeyboardAvoidingView is not working with multilines

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/Ae2Feec) Here the three firsl lines stay abov the keyboard.
[link](https://imgur.com/MgZ61MO) More than three lines they go under the keyboard.

[link](https://imgur.com/4WpRFjQ)
and if I unfocuse the keyboard and click on the bottom line, the textinput is pushed up again. But I need it to push the screen up without unfocusing and focusing again on every new line

Comment: @Malu123 i have the same issue. Its a bug in React-Native: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16826 Hopefully someone here can solve this.

Comment: @Malu123 I sort of solved it...I had a height set on the TextInput. I removed the height and the KeyboardAvoidingView is working now but it only moves half a line at a time...but it is moving now!

Comment: @Malu123 Try `keyboardVerticalOffset={some_number}`  and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be a little too late. However, I have found a workaround without using the `KeyboardAvoidingView` component. A `ScrollView` could be used instead to scroll the multiline `TextInput` to the top to have the 'keyboard avoiding' effect. I would use the ref `measure()` method to get the top y value of the `TextInput`, before using the `scrollTo()` method to scroll the `TextInput` directly to the top of the screen, effectively avoiding the keyboard.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { ScrollView, TextInput, View } from "react-native";

export default function Test() {
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);
  const viewRef = useRef(null);

  const handleFocus = () => {
    viewRef.current.measure((x, y) => {
    scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ x: 0, y });
    });
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef}>
      {/* View to fill up space */}
     <View
       style={{
        width: "80%",
        height: 600,
        }}
      />

     <View ref={viewRef}>
       <TextInput
         onFocus={handleFocus}
         multiline={true}
        style={{
          width: "80%",
          height: 100,
          backgroundColor: "whitesmoke",
          alignSelf: "center",
         }}
       />

      {/* View to fill up space */}
       <View
        style={{
         width: "80%",
         height: 600,
        }}
        />
   </View>
  </ScrollView>
 );
}
```